# Moment.js formatting time incorrectly?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, timezone, momentjs

```
moment.tz('2017-03-26T01:00:00', 'Europe/London').utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:00')
```

returns: "2017-03-26T01:00:00Z" correctly

```
moment.tz('2017-03-26T02:00:00', 'Europe/London').utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:00')
```

returns: "2017-03-26T01:00:00" instead of "2017-03-26T02:00:00"

```
moment.tz('2017-03-26T02:00:00Z', 'Europe/London').utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:00')
```

returns "2017-03-26T02:00:00"

why is this?

Comment: The format seems correct, is your issue the timezone offset value? If so, you might need to change the title.

Answer (score 2):

On March 26, 2016, [DST began in London](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/uk/london?year=2016).  By 2:00, the offset was UTC+01:00.  Therefore, it is not going to be the same local time as UTC.